# How to use cv2.FileStorage

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.1

I used to FileStorage class in opencv c++ and it's very useful but i can't find how to use it in opencv python. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Something like: `fs = cv2.FileStorage("foo.yml", 0) fs.getNode("bar").mat()` shuld work...

Comment: thanks but how to write?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/write a matrix from a persistent XML/YAML file in OpenCV 3 with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056880/how-to-read-write-a-matrix-from-a-persistent-xml-yaml-file-in-opencv-3-with-pyth)

Answer (score 2):

```
`import cv2
 import numpy as np
 f = cv2.FileStorage('test.yml',flags=1)
 a = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=np.uint8)
 f.write(name='matrix',value=a)
 f.release()
`
```

the result is in 'test.yml'
'

```
%YAML:1.0
---
matrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 10
   cols: 10
   dt: u
   data: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Comment: What does the `flags=1` mean?

Comment: Please, refer to the cv::FileStorage::Mode in https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da4/group__core__xml.html#ga973e41cb75ef6230412a567723b7482d

Comment: Assuming the enum is defined **with no explicit values** it is WRITE. Is that right?